# Upgrading during a purchase process

Tags: purchase

Thanks in advance for any advice. I imagine this question has been asked in another form here at some point but I have not found good direction, so here it goes.

I am building out a UI for a user who is purchasing software on a system with an on-board OS. During the purchase process the user

1. Selects the desired edition
2. Selects their OS and purchase protection options
3. Configures their software add-ons (which is a very lengthy and complex process in an of itself),
4. Review and check out.

[image]

When the user is at step 3, it is possible they will choose so many add-ons that a different edition of the software would be more cost-effective for them than the selected version. I'm looking for the most graceful and least intrusive way to handle this for the user. I have two ways in mind, neither of which I am married to:

1) Provide a popover letting the user know that their cost with the upgraded versions would be less than with the current. If they choose to upgrade, the popover "yes" pushes them back to select options appropriate to that package (and provide them with an upgrade confirmation on that page).

2) Simply let them continue on in the process and cue them at Review time to upgrade at which point we push them back again to the "Select Options" step where they select options appropriate to their package type; again providing them with upgrade confirmation. (haven't designed the specific UI for this but generally something along these lines)

I hate to push the user backward in the process but the steps left pattern is already baked into our interface. I am leaning toward option 1 as it keeps the retreading minimal. Any advice, suggestions as to other ideas about why one or the other of these might be preferred is welcome. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**Both**.

**On the add/remove features page:** Provide a popup.

I would alert the user to this discovery as soon as you can so that they can either keep that in mind as they continue to add/remove addons, or update their selection immediately and avoid any additional unnecessary work.

I think it's also important to easily allow the user to dismiss or ignore this notification at this stage. I don't think it's far-fetched to imagine a situation where someone wants to add a bunch of features, then prune them off one by one until what remains is what they want. In this case, it would be useful to have a noticeable, but unobtrusive notification.

**On the review page:** Provide a non-dismissible warning block.

If the user chooses to ignore the first notification and continue to their review stage, it might be useful to provide a second warning on the review page.

In the "add/remove features" stage, the user is goal-driven, so they would be more prone to just clicking away a notification without reading it. In the review stage, they are in a quality-check mindset, so they would be much more likely to read and comprehend a message that's presented to them.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a single argument for option 2.

Usability is a measure of performance load - cognitive or physical. Given the offer is taken, both options send you back to the same point. With option 2 users will expend more time and effort - they are just going to look, make choices, and perform actions that will later be thrown to the bin.

Perhaps I have misunderstood the question, but why option 2 is even considered?

Comment: Would you not consider *both* to be a reasonable option? I agree that the first option is definitely better--let the user know that the option is available as soon as it's detectable--but option two seems like a fail-safe for a user who, for whatever reason, doesn't see the first warning. This is not to say that every warning should be given twice, but it seems appropriate to give on the page where the decision is made (when it's being made) and also on the review page (when the decisions are being reviewed).

Comment: Option 2 is considered because the user will literally potentially save thousands of dollars- its a purchase typically being made by an enterprise client. Giving the user the opportunity to back out of a costly decision is good UCD, even if the cognitive load is high. Someone could lose their job in this case for costing a company thousands more dollars than they could have. I definitely am going to suggest to our project lead to offer both.

Comment: I've also seen users dismiss modals without reading. With these users this is less likely but as Max mentioned, more failsafe. I know I personally would appreciate the reminder that I can save money by putting forth extra effort if I happen to overlook it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [maxathousand's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/99000/57088) that both would be useful –`enter preformatted text here` an alert when it becomes economic to switch the base edition, and a hard warning before final checkout (in light of the potential savings involved).

However – if feasible – it might be helpful to add a "live comparison" panel to the add-on selection screen that shows what the costs would be of the current selection, but starting with different base editions. For example, if you have three editions, *Gold*, *Silver* and *Bronze*, then you might show:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjiziZ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

where *Silver* is the currently-selected base edition, but it has just become more economic to switch to the *Gold* edition. (You would typically highlight the *Gold* row in some manner, as well as showing a pop-up). This also allows you to limit the number of pop-ups: the *first* time a user crosses an "edition boundary", you can show a pop-up, explaining there is a more economic way of getting what they want; thereafter, you only need to highlight rows in the comparison table.

**Note**: If you have *many* base-editions, you would probably only show the variant either side of the currently-selected edition, otherwise the table would become unwieldy.

I *presume* it goes without saying that whenever you switch to a different base edition, the user's current add-on choice will be preserved. For example, suppose they selected *Bronze Edition* and add-ons **A**, **B**, **C** and **D**. It now makes sense to start with the *Silver Edition* (which comes with **A** and **B** included in the price). On making the switch, add-ons **C** and **D** should remain selected (or get pre-selected).

Answer (score 0):

I would:

On the software selection page, as the user is adding additional software items to their order, I would pop-up a notification or at least create a notification in the users eyeline, that informs them that with the options selected Option X would be better value for money, detailing what is in option X.

Give the user two simple paths to proceed with your recommendation or continue with their own.

Once the decision is made, don't bother them again, unless they change the core software products that prompted the original interruption.